# OpenGL Texture wierd lines

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, textures

So i am trying to render multiple textures with texture batching in opengl and with Java. However, for a long time I have been stuck on a very specific point. Whenever I try to render these textures it looks like this:

This is what it looks like with the bug:

[image: this is what it looks like with the bug]

That it should roughly look like:

[image: what it should roughly look like]

The colors of the other textures seem to overlap in some way, although I'm sure this doesn't actually happen. Maybe someone who had to fight with the same problem can help me. I also work with a vertex and fragment shader. If asked, I could send certain parts of the source code, but it is quite a lot and I am very unsure where exactly the problem lies.

> VertexShader

```
#version 440 

layout(location=0) in vec3 vertex_pos;
layout(location=1) in vec4 vertex_color;
layout(location=2) in vec2 uv_cords;
layout(location=3) in float tex_index;

uniform mat4 ModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 ViewMatrix;

out vec4 fragment_color;
out vec2 o_uv_cords;
out float o_tex_index;

void main(){

    fragment_color = vertex_color;
    o_uv_cords = uv_cords;
    o_tex_index = tex_index;


    gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(vertex_pos, 1.0f);


}
```

> FragmentShader

```
#version 440

uniform sampler2D TextureSampler[3];

in vec4 fragment_color;
in vec2 o_uv_cords;
in float o_tex_index;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{

    int id = int(o_tex_index);

    color = texture(TextureSampler[id], o_uv_cords);
}
```

> Texture.java

```
textureID = glGenTextures();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

IntBuffer width = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
IntBuffer height = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
IntBuffer channels = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
ByteBuffer image = stbi_load(filePath, width, height, channels, 0);

if(image == null)
{
    return false;
}

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width.get(0), height.get(0), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);


stbi_image_free(image);
```

Comment: An array of samplers may only be indexed by a dynamic uniform expression. A varying is never dynamically unform. See [Will any of the following texture lookups cause undefined behavior, non-uniform flow, or both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734640/will-any-of-the-following-texture-lookups-cause-undefined-behavior-non-uniform), [In a fragment shader, why can't I use a flat input integer to index a uniform array of sampler2D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388274/in-a-fragment-shader-why-cant-i-use-a-flat-input-integer-to-index-a-uniform-ar)

Comment: [Dynamic indexing into uniform array of sampler2D doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63031123/dynamic-indexing-into-uniform-array-of-sampler2d-doesnt-work),

Comment: Thank you so mutch this helped me a lot and i could fix the bug. Thank you